# Ideas for an exersice project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to get  better experienced with the new release of the MVC framework. I want to start building my own project on my free time. I would like to get a business (or close to real business) idea or purpose  to start building around. What I mean is that I need a challenge, not just throwing a couple of pages to touch a few areas of the framework.

I would like to use the set of these components:

MVC 2.0
.net 4.0
IoC container
Linq2Sql
jQuery

What have you done to learn a technology for the homework project? Is it hosted somewhere and if so - can you post link?

Comment: I would recommend `Entity Framework` over `Linq 2 SQL` because Microsoft has said they will be focusing on `EF` as their primary ORM.

Answer (score 2):

Just buy/download this:

> [Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework](http://apress.com/book/view/1430228865)

This book explains how to build a nice  asp-net-mvc-2 application step by step (chapter by chapter). Although it can be tough to learn all the tecnologies you've mentioned at one time(i assume you do not know much about these), you can give it a try.

PS That's how I've got started with mvc, and it is one of the best books on programming i've ever read.

Thanks, Ilya.

Comment: "I would like to get a business (or close to real business) idea or purpose to start building around."  Book code is the farthest thing from real world possible.

Answer (score 2):

Online Shop

CRUD

```
Create, display, update and delete categories/products
```

Membership

```
User accounts
OpenId
```

Cache

```
Cache e.g. product data
OutputCache + RenderAction()
```

Session

```
Store previously viewed products
```

Ajax + JQuery

```
Use ajax to add items to the shopping basket
Nice UI effects, e.g. tabs with animation
Load json from an action and display it
```

Dependency injection

```
Different implementations for repositories, membership provider, logger...
Custom ControllerFactory
```

Mvc areas

```
Separate area for admin
```

Validation

```
Data annotations
```

Misc

```
Custom HtmlHelper extension methods
ActionFilters (e.g. for saving visitor details)
```

Answer (score 0):

Build something that will need all of the basic CRUD operations. A blog engine typically requires this, but there are other options as well.

**C** reate blog entries and comments
**R** ead blog entries for list and details
**U** pdate posts you've entered
**D** elete nasty comments

This should give you at two Controllers (Post and Comment) though maybe just one, and a hand full of Views to display your content.

Comment: Why the -1? Is there something inaccurate or wrong about my answer?

Comment: "What I mean is that I need a challenge, not just throwing a couple of pages to touch a few areas of the framework."  I think the the answerer is asking for something more than this.  A blog/comment system couldn't be more mundane.  ;)  The guy says NOT just a couple of pages and you say "you just need a couple of pages".

Comment: That would be the most simple implementation once could do; imagine a blog engine such as DasBlog or BlogEngine.NET -- re-creating those would take a significant amount of effort. I figured that leaving the extensible points to the OP would be sufficient.

Comment: @NateBoss So is your answer make a two "maybe just one" controller with "a hand full of views" or re implement an feature right blog engine? ;)